# Kendo Scheduler events do not resize and follow Scheduler when Scheduler is resized?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, kendo-scheduler

We have need to make the kendo scheduler visible when the create/edit popup is brought up (by double clicking an event already there, or a free spot on the scheduler), so we resize the scheduler and fit the popup off to the right in the space now open. I have it resizing using the open, close, activate, and deactivate events of the window to control when to resize the scheduler.

However, when it resizes, the events stay the same size and don't move while the days in the week and month view squish with the resize, making all the events out of place until the scheduler refreshes. However, when refreshing after resizing the scheduler, the edit/create popup closes, which throws an exception because the scheduler edit event can no longer find components that were defined in the edit html template...

Is there a good way to resize the scheduler and have events follow the resize on edit/create popup open?

Here is are my window event functions for open, activate, close, deactivate as well as the very beginning of my scheduler initialization, which sets the edit window with its options.

```
function openCreateEditPopup(e){
            console.log('opening edit window', e);
            console.log($('#scheduler'));
            $('#scheduler')[0].style.width = '988px';

            e.sender.wrapper[0].style.paddingTop = '0px';
            e.sender.wrapper[0].style.left = '';
            e.sender.wrapper[0].style.right = '0px';
            console.log($('.k-overlay'));

            //scheduler.view(scheduler.view().name);

        }
function finishOpeningEditPopup(e){
            $('.k-overlay')[0].style.display = 'none';
            //scheduler.view(scheduler.view().name);
        }
        function closeCreateEditPopup(e){
            $('#scheduler')[0].style.width = '100%'; 
            //scheduler.view(scheduler.view().name);
        }
        function finishClosingEditPopup(e){
            //scheduler.view(scheduler.view().name);
        }
        function createScheduler(resources, setUp) {

            var AgendaDayView = kendo.ui.AgendaView.extend({
                endDate: function(){
                    var date = kendo.ui.AgendaView.fn.startDate.call(this);
                    //console.log('custom agenda date: ', date);
                    return date;
                },
                name: 'Day Agenda'
            });
            scheduler = $('#scheduler').kendoScheduler({
                pdf: {
                    fileName: 'Current Schedule View.pdf',
                    proxyTarget: '_blank'
                },
                date: new Date(),
                startTime: new Date(),
                showWorkHours: false,
                //timezone: "America/Chicago",
                editable: {
                    editRecurringMode: 'occurrence',
                    move: false,
                    resize: false,
                    template: $("#editor_template").html(),
                    window: {
                        title: 'Event',
                        width: 432,
                        open: openCreateEditPopup,
                        activate: finishOpeningEditPopup,
                        close: closeCreateEditPopup,
                        deactivate: finishClosingEditPopup
                    }
                },
```